# Построить предполагаемых план со временными таблицами

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли как-нибудь построить успешно план выполнения если в запросе|процедуре используется инструкция `SELECT * INTO #TMP FROM TABLE` ?

Хоть при боевом вызове все корректно выполняется, но предполагаемый план построить не получается и ругается на то, что объект #TMP не найден...

Неужели единственное решение- это явное создание #TMP через CREATE TABLE или есть какие-то альтернативы?

Comment: Странно, кстати, что у вас на `SELECT * INTO #TMP FROM TABLE` ругается. Проверил, предполагаемый план строится. Вот для `INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT * FROM TABLE` не строит, ругается, что логично.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как альтернатива - использовать не временную таблицу, а табличную переменную. В принципе, это плохая альтернатива ибо всё равно объявлять заранее нужно.
Но для построения предполагаемого плана все объекты должны быть известны

Comment: Временные таблицы тормознутые и не отображают реальный план. Например, в них невозможны параллельные операции, на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Ты  про табличные переменные наверно )) Да, есть в них неудобства определенные. Но вроде как подсказки в запросах могут иногда исправлять эти неудобства

Comment: Не стоит так делать, табличная переменная не поддерживает статистику, а значит оптимизатор предполагает, что любой запрос, выполняющийся к табличной переменной или UDF, возвратит всего одну строку.

Comment: _"Но для построения предполагаемого плана все объекты должны быть известны"_ плюсую